# Walktrought installing angular-gettext in ionic

Tags: angularjs, installation, ionic-framework, angular-gettext

I'me trying to get angular-gettext to work in ionic. 
Could someone explain how to do that?
There aren't any good explanations out there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Even thought this question is quite old, I still could not recently find much information on how to adapt the [angular-gettext Getting Started guide](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/getting-started/) to an Ionic app. So here is how I did it with IonicV1 and German (de_DE) translations:

---

**[1) Install angular-gettext](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/install/)**

I added the `<script>` section in the main html file `index.html` and added the angular module to `app.run.js`.

---

**[2) Annotate translations](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/annotate/)**

One thing not highlighted enough in the official guide is that you can annotate strings in the JS file by using `gettextContent.getString('English text')` 
String 'English text' will be picked automatically for translation, similarly to what happen to tags marked with directive `translate`.

---

**[3) Extract strings](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/extract/)**

I used angular-gettext-cli as I didn't use grunt in my Ionic project. From your project root, create a folder `i18n` and then:

```
angular-gettext-cli --files './app/**/*.+(js|html)' --exclude '**/*.spec.js' --dest './i18n/extract.pot' --marker-name i18n
```

---

**[4) Translate strings](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/translate/)**

The guide perfectly explains how to use [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) to build a `.po` file out of the `.pot` template.

---

**[5) Compile translations](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/compile/)**

angular-gettext-cli helps building translation.js containing all translated text in Javascript format.

```
angular-gettext-cli --compile --files './i18n/de_DE_t.po' --dest './app/translations.js' --format javascript --module gettext
```

This will create a file `translations.js` containing all translations.

---

**6) Enable transaltions** (not part of angular-gettext guide)

I then added `translations.js` created at previous step to `index.html`:

```
<script src="app/translations.js"></script>
```

And concluded by specifying the language to be used in `app.run.js`:

```
var appLanguage = window.navigator.language || window.navigator.userLanguage;
gettextCatalog.setCurrentLanguage(appLanguage);
```